# Flutter websockets working in local web but not in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, websocket, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I'm doing some tests with [web_socket_channel Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) and I've noticed a very strange behavior. I've implemented [flutter-dev's example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets), just changing the socket kind to `HtmlWebSocketChannel` in order to make it work in web builds.
If I compile my app with `flutter build web --release` and later I expose it with  a local webserver, it works perfectly fine. Same happens if I execute it in debug mode.

However, if I deploy the release version to Firebase hosting (`firebase deploy`), the widgets where a `HtmlWebSocketChannel` is present are rendered as a grey box. If I remove those instances, all widgets are rendered as usual.
I thought Firebase hosting was nothing more that a very simple web server, I can't see how can it interfere with specific widgets in a Flutter app. Maybe the cause is related to the fact I'm accesing a remote URL?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here's the code of the app I'm deploying:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/html.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: HtmlWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: widget.channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      widget.channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Firebase hosting by default hosts with a `https` secure environment. So communication with any non secure server will be blocked by the browser. Check if chrome is blocking it. If you can find and post the error from the chrome console, or network tab we can try something.

Comment: Also try switching to `wss://echo.websocket.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above in my comments this seems to be an issue with trying to access insecure resource from a secure environment as `https`. Here is a working demo of the same code you used.

https://stackoverlfow-demos.web.app/#/

I just replaced it with `wss` and deployed it to the firebase hosting.

```dart
channel: HtmlWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://echo.websocket.org'),
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. I definetly have should check the console!